# Manage multiple servers

Tags: shell-script

I wrote a simple script that I want to run on several hosts. (I.e., I want to run one *instance* of the script, but have it operate on several hosts.) The script works, but only for the first host. When I add more than one host, I get an error stating:

```
line 3: MACHINE2: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong? The script is posted below.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOSTS=MACHINE1 MACHINE 2

for i in $HOSTS; do echo $i
    ssh -q $i uname -a;
done
```

Comment: You need to put the list of hosts in quotes: `HOSTS="MACHINE1 MACHINE2"`

Comment: Thanks Andy. The most mind boggling thing happened. I added the quotation marks but I still got the same error messages. 
     
I then copied and pasted your quotation marks into my script and it worked. I'm using a mac. not sure if that makes a difference..but thats a little odd.

Comment: Use the command hexdump to find out if quotation marks differ

Answer (score 1):

A command like

```
xyz=abc def ghi jkl
```

means to run the `def` program with arguments `ghi` and `jkl`,
and with environment variable `xyz` set to `abc`.  To set `HOSTS` to the string

```
MACHINE1 MACHINE 2
```

you would need to say

```
HOSTS="MACHINE1 MACHINE 2"
```

(although I assume that you don't want to have a space
between the second `MACHINE` and the `2`.) 
You could probably get that to work,
since hostnames don't contain spaces or other special characters. 
However, it might be smarter to use an array:

```
HOSTS=(MACHINE1 MACHINE2)

for i in "${HOSTS[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    ssh -q "$i" uname -a
done
```

This structure let you have multi-word array elements with special characters:

```
lyrics=("Twinkle twinkle little *" "How I wonder what you are")

for line in "${lyrics[@]}"
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```

Note that you should always quote all shell variable references
(e.g., `"${HOSTS[@]}"` and `"$i"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing. 
Also,

- You don't need semicolons at the ends of lines.
- It’s usual in shell scripts to use lower case for script variable names
  since ALL UPPER CASE is traditionally used for system variables.
- `echo` is handy for printing fixed strings,
  but it can do unexpected things with arbitrary data. 
  It’s *far* safer to use `printf`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The most mind boggling thing happened. I added the quotation marks but I still got the same error messages.

Comment: I then copied and pasted your quotation marks into my script and it worked. I'm using a mac. not sure if that makes a difference..but thats a little odd.